# how can I add row and columns in table heading in react material UI

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, html-table, material-ui, material-design

I am new to material UI and I am struggling to add columns in the table heading, I have provided an image I am trying to do like this, under the Economics there will be 3 columns also each column will take two more columns.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
           <StyledTableCell align="left" scope="col">
                Economics
                <StyledTableCell align="left" scope="col">
                  1st
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">CQ</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">MCQ</StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="left">
                  2nd
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">CQ</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">MCQ</StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="left">
                  AVG
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">%</StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCell align="left">GP</StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
```

The above code UI is like the below screenshot, it's too big and not aligned

[image]

I have used the `scope="col"` attribute inside the StyledTableCell but it's not working, is there anything that I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this `colSpan` attribute

`<StyledTableCell  colSpan={6}>`

you can check it here. in the spanning section
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/

your code will look like this

```
   <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={6}>
          Economics
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={2}>
          1st
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={2}>
          2nd
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={2}>
          AVG
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell align="center">CQ</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">MCQ</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">CQ</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">MCQ</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">%</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">GP</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  </Table>
```